# use python to simulate sending user input to spim

Tags: mips, mips32, qtspim, spim

I am trying to write a program in python that can run
SPIM 
and send user input to the SPIM subroutine

I tried using

```
mips=subprocess("spim",stdin=PIPE, stdout=output.txt, stderr=output.txt)
mips.stdin.write(b"10")
mips.stdin.write(b"15")
mips.stdin.write(b"15")
```

but it completely skipped waiting for user input

Here is what the mips subroutine is supposed to do

```
enter first value: 10
enter second value: 15
enter third value: 15
your Sum is: 40
```

this works correctly when i call it from terminal and enter values myself but if i run it as a subprocess it prints the following

```
enter first value: 
enter second value: 
enter third value: 
your Sum is: 101515
```

the 101515 appears to be printing after spim execution completes

what can i do to programatically enter values into the spim virtual machine

If it helps SPIM is pts not tty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To programmatically send input to spin you place the values in a text file and pipe in

Each value on a new line

So if the mips prompts were

"Enter string"

"Enter digit"

The text file must look as follows with each separate input  on its own line

My string input

127

And in terminal you type the following

spim asm-name.s < input-file.txt

Comment: You don't have to use an input file. That's the whole point of the pipes.